# NodeJS object method keeps returning null

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Lets say I have this object:

```
function MyObject(initval) {
     this.myVal = initval;
}

MyObject.prototype.boundaries = function(howmuch, callback) {
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(this.myVal-howmuch);
    arr.push(this.myVal+howmuch);
    callback(arr);
};

MyObject.prototype.getBoundaries = function(howmuch) {
    this.boundaries(howmuch, function(arr) {
        console.log(arr); //returns null
        return arr;
    });
};
```

I'm invoking `getBoundaries` inside an `async.parallel` and my `MyObject` array is defined globally.

`arr = myObject[index].getBoundaries(5); //null here too`

Any ideas why I keep getting null?

**Edit:**

To those who are requesting how I'm creating myObject

```
var myObject = [];
myObject.push(new MyObject(1));
myObject.push(new MyObject(2));
```

**Edit for async portion**

```
var arr;
var asycnTasks = [];

(function(arr) {
    for(i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
        (function(i) {
             asyncTasks.push(function(callback) {
                 arr.push(myObject[i].getBoundaries(5));   
                 callback();    
             });
        })(i);
    }
})(arr);

async.parallel(asyncTasks, function() {
    //should have arr != null but is null
});
```

Comment: uhm.... How did `myObject` become an array? `var myObject = new MyObject('foo')` would give you an instance of `MyObject` that has properties, it isn't an array.

Comment: What `index` doing there?

Comment: Please show how you're creating `myObject`.

Comment: myObject != MyObject. myObject is defined globally as stated, 'var myObject = []'.

Comment: @sc2bigjoe You stated _MyObject array is defined globally_ not `myObject`

Comment: How are you populating `myObject` array? (the naming of all these things is so confusing... constructors named object, arrays named object, etc)

Comment: yeah myObject is an array of MyObject, that I defined globally. phrasing?

Comment: [it seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/pf1wtxe1/)

Comment: My guess is whatever was wrong, you fixed it when asking the question while abstracting out the not important parts.

Comment: no, because the JS fiddle you linked completely omits async.parallel

Comment: No matter how you call it the result should be the same. Can you give an example of the async portion?

Comment: added example of async

Comment: you have a classic for loop scope issue. Not sure how you even got to the success of async.parallel... I see, you just fixed it in edit.

Comment: I see `undefined`, but i guess that's what you mean.

Comment: Working on it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/dMEGyCKrNZ4O5HUm4W4d?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works;

```
MyObject.prototype.getBoundaries = function(howmuch) {
    var result = null;
    this.boundaries(howmuch, function(arr) {
        result = arr;
    });
    return result;
};
```

But I am not sure if a callback is necessary when this is not an asynchronous operation.

Comment: and here's a plunkr of this fixing it http://plnkr.co/edit/5qADC5nF7BnSnwGDwdtq?p=preview

Comment: thanks! callback was not necessary I was just seeing if returning it over a callback had a different effect on the return value